# As3 split strangeness

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript-3, split, backslash

Super simple example:

```
var Path:String="E:\SWF Security\Acess Current Path\Access SWF URL.swf" 

var Path1:Array = Path.split("\\") // Split using the backslash as delimiter (No limit the number of returned tokens) 

trace(Path1)
```

What do you expect path1 to be ?
E: ?
No its E:SWF SecurityAcess Current PathAccess SWF URL.swf and i have no idea why.

Comment: Ah its just because i hardcoded the string without escaping it ...

Answer (score 1):

In this situation you should use forward-slash instead of back-slash in your path. AS3 will treat them as the same when you're trying to load a file.

Then you can split using Path.split("/");